# I am not able to send more than 100 mails from google apps scripts. How to increase mail sending limits from App scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I am not able to send more than 100 mails from google apps scripts. How to increase mail sending limits from App scripts?

Gsuite has provided limits of 500 mails per day.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MailApp then try using GmailApp. If you've just moved from a regular gmail account to Gsuite there's a one month wait period before you can switch to the higher rate. If you're sending emails real fast in a loop you mail also have hit the limit if you send them to fast. All of their daily quotas actually become rates and if you exceed the rate then you mail see a error like this service had too many operations or something like that.